# How to make this graphing algorithm more efficient?

Tags: c#, algorithm, data-structures

I have written some code in C# to graph data points that are generated by a large polynomial equation ex:

```
y = (a*b*c*… + e*d*f*g *…*x + h*…*x*x +...)/(A*B*C*… + E*D*F*G*…*x +...)
```

where `a, b, c,... F, G` are known float coefficients and `x` is the variable

The way I stored the equation is by a numerator Arraylist of Arraylists and a denominator Arraylist of Arraylists (sum of products where each arraylist inside of numerator and denominator is a collection of either float coefficients or "x" string that are being multiplied together, and each result is being added together)

I then loop though all Arraylists in the numerator and loop through each coefficient or variable string in each of those and multiply everything out for each (substituting the current data point in for the string "x")and add each result to the final numerator result. I repeat the same for the denominator. I then divide the two for each data point.

Is there a more efficient algorithm for calculating these data points? My goal is to have a slider that the user can slide and in real time see how changing any of the coefficients will change the graph of a polynomial.

Edit, I think some ways to speed it up would be to move this line

```
float temp_y = helper_get_num_denom_total(start_x + del_x * i,  numer)/helper_get_num_denom_total(start_x + del_x*i, denom);
```

into the else bracket so that the extra computation isn't happening when the user doesn't want a logarithmic graph. Also I'm thinking of maybe pre-computing the totals of the multiplications of the known coefficients on the first iteration of the loop that aren't being changed so as to save on quiet a few multiplication opperations. Also I should mention that I only care about the absolute value of the end result

Edit, some of the code even though it is kinda messy(hopfully I got everything relevant):

```
    float del_x = Mathf.Abs(end_x - start_x) / num_points;
    //float del_y = Mathf.Abs(end_y - start_y) / num_points;

    float start_x_log = Mathf.Log(start_x, 10);
    /////////////////float del_x_log = Mathf.Log(Mathf.Abs(end_x - start_x), 10) / num_points;
    float del_x_log = Mathf.Abs((Mathf.Log(end_x, 10) - start_x_log)) / num_points; 
    Debug.Log("x log    end_x is: " + end_x + "  while start_x is: " + start_x);
    Debug.Log("start x log is: " + start_x_log + "del x log is: " + del_x_log);


    float[] points_x = new float[num_points];
    float[] points_y = new float[num_points]; 


    for (int i = 0; i<num_points; i++) {
        // substitute each value into 
        float temp_y = helper_get_num_denom_total(start_x + del_x * i, numer)/helper_get_num_denom_total(start_x + del_x*i, denom);

        if (logrithmic == true) {

            points_x[i] = start_x_log + del_x_log * i;
            points_y[i] = 20f*Mathf.Log(helper_get_num_denom_total(Mathf.Pow(10, points_x[i]), numer) / helper_get_num_denom_total(Mathf.Pow(10, points_x[i]), denom), 10);
            Debug.Log("inside processing, new x-y is: (" + points_x[i] + ", " + points_y[i] + ")");
        }
        else {
            ////////////////////points_y[i] = temp_y;
            points_x[i] = start_x + del_x * i;
            points_y[i] = temp_y;
            Debug.Log("current temp_y is: " + temp_y);
        }
    }


 /// and this method


public float helper_get_num_denom_total(float point_x, ArrayList   num_or_denom) {
    float total = 0; 
    for (int i = 0; i<num_or_denom.Count; i++) {
        ArrayList temp_arraylist;
        temp_arraylist = (ArrayList)num_or_denom[i];
        float temp_total = 1f;
        if (temp_arraylist.Count>0) {
            for (int j = 0; j < temp_arraylist.Count; j++) {
                string temp_string = temp_arraylist[j].ToString();
                float convert = 1;
                bool is_num = float.TryParse(temp_string, out convert);
                if (is_num == true) {
                    temp_total = temp_total * convert;
                }
                else if (string.Equals(temp_string, "x")) {
                    //Debug.Log("inside helper get num denom total, S else if triggered");
                    temp_total = temp_total * point_x;
                }
            }
        }
        else {
            temp_total = 0f; 
        }
        total = total + temp_total;
        Debug.Log("inside helper get num denom total, total is: " + total);
    }
    total = Mathf.Abs(total);
    return total; 
}
```

Comment: Seeing the code might be helpful

Comment: *"Arraylist of Arraylists"* - `ArrayList` is old, you probably have to use one of generic collections, e.g. `List<T>`.

Comment: While this question look specific and define. There is no code. It's like trying to upgrade the performance of an engine only by listening a customer mimic it's sound. I know that an [mcve] could be an hard task there. But at some point we will ne to see something. IF you code is complete and 101% working perhaps code review may be fit. Still there will be some code.

Comment: Since the coefficients are fixed, you could compute them once and store them. To evaluate the numerator and denominator you can use [Horner's method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horner%27s_method).